# Not able to get the proper icons on the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creation the layout in android that has three column with image in each column, i have all types/size dpi images in drawable folder that is (hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi). but when i run this layout on device. it takes only ldpi image and shows on the screen, because of that i am getting so small icons.

Layout:

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:background="@drawable/menu_gradient"
                    android:text="@string/health_products"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:weightSum="100">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/anjir"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="35"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/drkshe"
                    android:layout_weight="35"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/sitafal"
                    android:layout_weight="35"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

[Click here to view layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv7ly.jpg)

[Image that shows directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC7iP.jpg)

as here in this layout under linear layout we have three ImageViews that shows icons. those Icons are in all size and dpi. but it takes only ldpi. so it shows small image. what should i do to get proper dpi image on layout.

Comment: can you update your question with the image of drawables in their respective folder?

Comment: @siddhesh i have updated the directory structure image.